# Reshape multiple related dataframes for weighted averages in R

Tags: r

I'm trying to calculate weighted averages from a complex set of dataframes that are stored in a list.  Here is a much simplified example

```
dfs <- structure(list(TZ = structure(list(row.names = c(168L, 302L), 
    type = c(1.5, 25.35), zone = c(43.53, 87.65)), .Names = c("row.names", 
"type", "zone"), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -2L)), 
    Weight = structure(list(row.names = c(168L, 302L), `1` = c(TRUE, 
    FALSE), `2` = c(TRUE, TRUE)), .Names = c("row.names", "1", 
    "2"), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -2L)), Number = structure(list(
        row.names = c(168L, 302L), `1` = c(6L, 9L), `2` = c(8L, 
        6L)), .Names = c("row.names", "1", "2"), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
    -2L))), .Names = c("TZ", "Weight", "Number"))
```

where `TZ` serves as a classifier/identifier of the data, `Weight` contains weights for use in `weighted.mean` (I need to convert `TRUE` to 1 and `FALSE`to 0), and `Number` contains the data that I want to use for the weighted average calculation.  Note that the structure of `TZ` differs from `Weight` and `Number`, but **importantly** `row.names` is consistent across all dataframes and this is how I can associate the data between dataframes. My real data contains a number of additional dataframes for which I want to do the same operations (these are consistent with each other and with this simple example).

The result I"m trying to achieve is

```
result <- structure(list(row.names = c(168L, 302L), type = c(1.5, 23.35
), zone = c(43.53, 87.65), Num.Wht = c(7L, 6L)), .Names = c("row.names", 
"type", "zone", "Num.Wht"), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-2L))

    row.names   type    zone    Num.Wht
1   168         1.50    43.53   7
2   302         23.35   87.65   6
```

where `Num.Wht` is weighted average of `Number` weighted by `Weight` (after converting to 1s and 0s). Note that in my real data, I will have many additional dataframes, and thus columns containing weighted averages.

Can anyone recommend a good strategy for proceeding?  I was thinking to first `melt` then `merge` my dataframes `Weight` and `Number` so I could then use `weighted.mean`

```
library(reshape2)
test1 <- melt(dfs$Weight, id="row.names")
colnames(test1)[2:3] <- c("Time", "Weight")
test2 <- melt(dfs$Number, id="row.names")
colnames(test2)[2:3] <- c("Time", "Number")
```

However when using

```
test <- merge(test1, test2, by.x="row.names", by.y="row.names")
```

or

```
test <- merge(test1, test2, by.x="test1$row.names", by.y="test$2row.names")
```

I get an error

```
Error in fix.by(by.x, x) : 'by' must specify a uniquely valid column
```

I also tried first `merge` the dataframes before reshaping, like

```
dat <- merge(dfs$TZ, dfs$Weight, by.x="row.names", by.y="row.names")
```

However this is giving the same error.  (Curiously, this does work in my real data.)

I also tried changing `row.names` in `Weight` and `Number`, `merge` is giving me different columns for `Time.x` and `Time.y`

```
colnames(test1) <- c("Row.names", "Time", "Weight")
colnames(test2) <- c("Row.names", "Time", "Number")
test <- merge(test1, test2, by.x="Row.names", by.y="Row.names")
```

**Can anyone recommend a better way for me to achieve my desired result?**  Once I can properly do this, I plan to do the weighted means using something like

```
# convert weight to 1 and 0
test$Weight <- test$Weight*1

lapply(dfs,function(d) ddply(d, .(Time), summarize, Num.Wht=weighted.mean(test$Number,test$Weight)))
```

Comment: I think some of your problem arises from the fact that calling `merge` with `by="row.names"` is supposed to actually use the rownames rather than a column named `"row.names"`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thomas, the problem with the merge is that data.frames already have a `row.names` attribute, so when you also have a column called `row.names` it doesn't know which one to choose for the merge (hence the message *'by' must specify a uniquely valid column*).

So, changing all the columns "row.names" to "id" to avoid conflicting names, you can do it like this:

```
#renaming columns
dfs <- lapply(dfs, function(df){names(df)[1]<- "id";df})

# merging all dfs
merged_dfs <- Reduce(function(x,y) merge(x,y, by="id"), dfs)

# calculating weighted average
merged_dfs$Num.Wht <- apply(merged_dfs[,4:7], 1, 
                            function(x) weighted.mean(x[3:4], as.numeric(x[1:2])))

# getting the end result you want
result <- merged_dfs[,-c(4:7)]
result
   id  type  zone Num.Wht
1 168  1.50 43.53       7
2 302 25.35 87.65       6
```

Comment: Thanks Carlos, your solution works great for my example, but I'm not able to rename "row.names" for my real data. In my example, "row.names" is a column, but in my real data these result from a sort.  Thus, renaming columns in my real data doesn't rename "row.names" but instead the first column ("Type" and "1" in my provided example).  Do you know how I can deal with this problem?  I have tried adding a new column "id" using rownames(), but this is problematic due to the different dimensions of the dataframes in my list.

Comment: @Thomas, if you are using the actual `row.names` in your original data set, and you do not have a column named `row.names`, you can skip the part of the column rename and do the merge with `row.names`: `Reduce(function(x,y) merge(x,y, by="row.names"), dfs)`

Comment: Thanks Carlos. When I try that, I get 11 warnings "In merge.data.frame(x, y, by = "row.names") : column name ‘Row.names’ is duplicated in the result".  (My real list has 13 dataframes in it.)

Comment: @Thomas, you are right, the `merge` will create a `Row.names` column that will mess up the `Reduce`. Try this, create an `id` column with `dfs <- lapply(dfs, function(df){df$id<- rownames(df);df})` and then run the merge reduce with the `id` column as before `merged_dfs <- Reduce(function(x,y) merge(x,y, by="id"), dfs)`.

Comment: Thanks again, Carlos.  When I try the lapply you suggested, it works for most of my dataframes, however I get an error "In df$id <- rownames(df) : Coercing LHS to a list" for 3 of the dataframes.  Two are not a problem (I don't later use these dataframes), however something really weird happens to my "Weight" dataframe and it gains a ton of extra columns, none of which are "id".  It would be nice to solve this issue, but on the other hand I figured out how to do the calculation the long way, so it's OK.  Thanks again for your help!

Comment: @Thomas, the problem is that it's hard to help without the real dataset. I can only try to guess what is going on, but it would be better with the real data on hands. Maybe you could post another question with the real data (or a more realistic dataset that mimics your data)! Glad I could somehow help!